# Remove helper text in Django forms

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have a form in Django for adding an object to an app. On the form I want to remove the helper text from the form. I have done this already in another form, but I can't seem to replicate the removal. Any ideas, my code is below:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Node

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class NodeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Node
        fields = ('nickname', 'address', 'date')
        help_texts = {
            'nickname': None,
            'address': None,
            'date': None
        }
        widgets = {
            'date': DateInput(),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redefine the constructor of the form class, like:

```
class NodeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NodeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['nickname'].help_text = ""
        self.fields['address'].help_text = ""
        self.fields['date'].help_text = ""
    class Meta:
        model = Node
        fields = ('nickname', 'address', 'date')
        widgets = {
            'date': DateInput(),
        }
```